# Why is the mother's name requested in visa application form?

Tags: visas, air-travel, applications, oman

Why in a visa request form they require to state mother name? And why only mother and not father?

Edit: a friend of mine is filling in visa request form for Oman and we were talking about it. I'm referring to mother's maiden name. I was just curious about the reason of such a request.

Comment: Which (of far more than 100) visa request form you talk about?

Comment: Your question needs more detail. ‘Mother’s maiden name’ is often requested as part of setting up log in security. Are you referring to that? Please clarify which part of which visa application form you’re referring to.

Comment: In English the definition of maiden name is: **a woman’s family name before marriage** ; some other languages use the term: **birth name** (Geburtsname), which is the name at birth and cannot (very few exceptions)  be changed.

Comment: @MarkJohnson this doesn't answer my question

Comment: Part of your question was: **And why only mother and not father?**

Answer (score 1):

Your mothers maiden name will tell you apart from others who have the same name.
As such it can be important when names are often used.

In some cases the visa office may want to check family travel history or some such.